# Migrating content databases

Tags: configuration, database, sql, content

I've just moved one of our SharePoint 2013 environments over to a new SQL server and I tested one of the content databases was able to connect and this was fine but I cannot figure out how to update the SharePoint Admin Database and the Config database so that SharePoint see's these on the new SQL server.

I've followed some guides but I cannot get this to work.

Genuinely feeling a bit stuck.

Answer (score 4):

You must use `cliconfg.exe` on each SharePoint server to point the 'old' SQL Server name (and instance if applicable) to the new SQL Server name (and instance if applicable). So if you had an old SQL Server name of OLDSQL and a new one of NEWSQL, you would run `cliconfg.exe` on each SharePoint server, go to the Alias tab, add an alias named OLDSQL. Set it to TCP/IP. In the Server name field, input NEWSQL.

You can then migrate all databases without updating any connection strings, but this is the only way to migrate the SharePoint Config/Admin databases.

Comment: where can I get cliconfg.exe from? I've seen this referenced but its not already on my SharePoint Server. (Windows Server 2012 R2).

Comment: It is built into Windows. Just go to Start -> Run, type in cliconfg.exe.

Answer (score 0):

You will get all the information about the migrating & attaching all SharePoint databases from new SQL location\instance from below given link.

[Move all databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx)